# How do I properly configure IAM roles for AWS Cognito to allow for login into an identity and user pool from a mobile app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-iam-policy

how would I go about properly configuring an IAM role to allow a user to sign into Cognito from my Swift app? I am currently getting the error: "Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool." when I try to use the Amplify signIn function. However, I thought I set everything up right. I configured my identity pool to be connected to my user pool. Just for testing because I am running into this problem, I have authenticated and unauthenticated access enabled for the pool. Also for testing, I have the CognitoPowerUser permission enabled for the role assigned to the pool as well as the default role. I double checked that the trust relationships for the role I created were correct as well and looked at other people's amplifyconfiguration and awsconfiguration to make sure everything checked out okay on my Swift app, so I think it is an IAM role issue rather than a config file issue. I can login into my using the Amplify SDK in Swift when I dont have the "CredentialProvider" field in the configuration files. However, when it is in the amplifyconfiguration.json and awsconfiguration.json file, I get the error mentioned above. Does anybody have advice on what I might be doing wrong? Sorry if this question doesn't make that much sense, my brain is kind of burnt out right now.